# Slow startup of Visual Studio 2008; waiting at "Loading UI Library" (msenvui.dll) step

Tags: visual-studio-2008

As of this morning, Visual Studio 2008 is taking a long time (order of minutes) to startup on my machine. I ran it with logging enabled (`devenv.exe  /log "C:\log.txt"`) and found that it is pausing at/after the following log entry:

```
<entry>
  <record>9</record>
  <time>2010/07/19 10:12:35.101</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>Microsoft Visual Studio</source>
  <description>Loading UI library</description>
  <guid>{DA9FB551-C724-11D0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}</guid>
  <path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\*\msenvui.dll</path>
</entry>
```

I also have ReSharper 5 and AnkhSVN 2.1 installed.

I'm running Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by running `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`. After doing so I had to repair the installations of AnkhSvn and ReSharper so that they worked correctly.

Comment: Mine would start and hang, this allowed the application to run again.